# PowerApps Custom Connector response type is string

Tags: powerapps

I have created a custom connector with REST Service which accepts Employee Id(username) and password as request and will receive the name of the employee.

everything is working fine but how to catch the response and show it in application

Answer (score 0):

Wrap the Custom Connector call in a `ClearCollect` statement.

**Example:**

- Add a button control to your app
- Set the `OnSelect` property to:

```
ClearCollect(colResponse,
    MyCustomConnector(
        {
            empId: "bob123",
            pw: "danger!!"
        }
    )
)
```

- Push the button.

This will make the Custom Connector call and store it in the `colResponse` collection.

Then, expose `colResponse` values in a textbox by setting the `Default` propery of the textbox to `colResponse.empName` or `First(colResponse.empName).empName` depending on the JSON response.